# How is the transmission matrix A calculated?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have this 2-port net

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb69m5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to calculate the net transmission matrix A by using the cascade connection of the single blocks. So I need to calculate first the A', A'', A''' transmission matrix.

So I have a hint: $$A' = \begin{bmatrix}
1       & Z_1  \\
0       & 1
 \end{bmatrix}$$

But I don't understand why A has these values

I know that I can write the system of transmission matrix:

\begin{cases} v_1 = a_{11} v_2 - a_{12} i_2 \\
i_1 = a_{21} v_2 - a_{22} i_2 \end{cases}

and I need to determine the coefficients

Comment: Why don't you expand A into a system of equations?

Comment: Is this Homework?

Comment: This is an example that I found in my book but there aren't more explanations, so I'm in difficult

Comment: What are all those vertical wires bringing to the party?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon the OP has edited the picture and, indeed, my comment is no longer needed. If you look at the edit history you'll understand what I mean and why I asked the question.